# Are wordcount limits only for first submission, or also for revised submissions?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, publishability

Are wordcount limits only for first submission, or also for revised submissions? I know that I could ask every individual journal, but is there any general understanding? My discipline is philosophy.

Comment: I think it's up to the individual preferences of the journal.  Keep in mind the purpose of limits is to reduce the cost and time requirements of production.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I'm not sure I agree. As a reader, I certainly appreciate if a paper is not too long. Therefore, I'd expect the limit to also be enforced in revised submissions. In my field, character count limits apply to abstracts and they are enforced by the submission system, regardless if it is a new submission or revision.

Comment: I tend to believe the limit, if any exists, is for both. Otherwise, it creates a loophole. Say, the limit is 5000 words. The first submission is 4000. The revised submission becomes 7000. How would the journal handle this situation?

Comment: I just guess. Likely one can let few characters to slip in during revision, but otherwise I can't see a single reason for why the limits could be different except for a specific recommendation from the referees. Say "this paper is excellent but section X must be expanded so and so...".

Comment: In the old days some journals had hard page limits (e.g. Applied Physics Letters was 3 pages in the journal - no exceptions) and provided some guidance about what word count might meet that page limit. However, until actually typeset it was impossible to actually determine if you had 3 pages, or 3 pages plus a few lines from the word count. It was painful to figure out how to cut a few choice words from the text to eliminate those 3 extra lines...

Comment: @Jon Custer Oh, as an editor I find it fascinating when I have to cut words without cutting content. It's like an exercise in exquisite efficiency.

Comment: @Alchimista Even when reviewers ask you to present more work, sometimes that is impossible because of wordcount limits.

Comment: @Philosopherofscience yes of course that it happens. I was possibilistic. I agree that a words limit run from submissions to camera ready manuscripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, there seems to be a consensus that it applies to both.